# Reading to char * always has same address

Tags: c++, queue, void, void-pointers

I have a struct like these:

```
struct Node {
    void *data;
    Node *l, *r;
}
```

And I should use function:

```
void push(Queue *q, void *data, int priority) {
    Node *n = new Node;
    n->data = data;

   // place node in queue
}
```

I'm trying to read strings in loop, but after that I got queue where all values in nodes are similar.

```
void read_input(Queue *q) {
    string s;
    int p;
    cin >> s >> p;

    // problem is here
    push(q, (void *) s.c_str(), p);
}

void main() {
    Queue *q = create();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        read_input(q);
    }
}
```

How can I fix that? Why `string s` always has the same address?

Comment: It's not c, so why you tagged it like that?

Comment: what is `create()`?

Comment: Can you post code for push, I think you are assigning address to data, instead of allocating and copying string in it

Comment: What is `Queue`? Post a [MCVE].

Comment: @Maxim Samburskiy  The local variable string s; has the same address.in each call of the function.

Comment: Does your `push()` function copy the data at `*data`?  Remember that your string `s` is a local variable and it gets destroyed after leaving the `read_input` function.

Comment: This probably happens here: you are pushing the `c_str` of the local variable `s` to your queue. Once the `read_input` function has finished, the `s` variable will be destroyed, and the pointer you've pushed will point to nothing. Please post the `push` function.

Comment: @Pras yes. So I should copy string inside push and it will be fixed?

Comment: @MaximSamburskiy you are using C++ so you shouldn't bother writing your own containers but you should use the std containers, in your case probably [`std::queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/).

Comment: @MichaelWalz it's a priority queue for education purposes, so I can't just use standart library

Comment: @MaximSamburskiy then most of the other comments apply. You need to push a copy. But why are you using `void` pointers in C++? This is a very bad idea. Remember, you're writing in C++, not in C.

Comment: @MichaelWalz yeah, I know but I can't change this struct because it defined in my task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are saving (temporary) pointers to the private internals of temporary objects of class std::string in your queue push call. They become invalid after leaving read_input, and may be even reused internally, so the pointer seems not to change.

Instead you should work with copies, allocate your own memory for the strings.

Answer (score 2):

Like Trantor said, you using s.c_str() which is a private pointer of string s; and is valid only inside read_input function.

Every call to read_input will use this pointer that is destroyed every time you reach read_input end (out of scope).

You see the same pointer, probably because its on the stack. Its a coincidence.

To fix your issue, you need to create a copy of the characters and store them in node->data. However you will also need to think where to delete it. E.g. OnNodeDestroy event or similar.

Answer (score 1):

When you have created a string object compiler will allocate the memory from stack  and all the time that string object will pointing to that particular memory  location (static memory allocation in this case) only. In your structure void *data pointer will also always pointing to that same memory location. Hence the last value entered into string object will  reflect in all the node in your stack. To fix this you have to dynamically allocate memory each time so that the data pointer should pointing to different memory location and you will get different value.

```
void read_input(Queue *q) {
    //string s;
    char *s = (char *)malloc(50);
    int p;
    cin >> s >> p;
    push(q, (void *) s, p);
}
```